# How to make perl number constant to be always a number when serializing to json

Tags: perl

Here is the code that is working as I expect:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature qw(say);

use constant MY_CONSTANT => 42;

use JSON::XS;

say encode_json { value => MY_CONSTANT };
```

This code output:

```
{"value":42}
```

But if the constant is used in string concatenation, then instated of a number in json I get string:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature qw(say);

use constant MY_CONSTANT => 42;

use JSON::XS;

say encode_json { value => MY_CONSTANT };

my $smth = 'asdf' . MY_CONSTANT;
```

Here is the output:

```
{"value":"42"}
```

For me it was very unexpected that the "constant" changes it behaviour depending of how it it used.

Is there a way to define a constant with number in perl that will be converted to number value in json even it is used in concatenation.

Comment: The weird behaviour is because JSON::XS tries to guess the type of value of a scalar, but that's not how Perl works. In Perl, you operations drive the type, not the other way around. e.g., you use `eq` if you want to compare as a string, and you `==` if you want to compare as a number.

Comment: Note that Cpanel::JSON::XS doesn't have that problem. (It also fixes other problems JSON::XS has.) And it has Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type to bring the aforementioned Perl approach to JSON generation.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like with Cpanel::JSON::XS everything is indeed working as I expect.

Comment: But it means that you have the converse problem with Cpanel::JSON::XS. Instead of generating a string for `my $x = 123; "" . $x;`, it generates a number for `my $x = "123"; 0 + $x;`. But like I said, that can be resolved by using Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type.

Comment: Yep. Thank you. It looks like using Cpanel::JSON::XS solves the problem that I've describe in the quesition, but it does not work as I would like it to work in this example https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/c12a062692f78a0307e369e928e07b74

Comment: Yes, I already addressed that. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, Perl considers fourty-two to be fourty two, whether you initialized the variable using `"42"` or `42`. JSON::XS breaks that model, which causes results like the ones you saw.

You could use a sub (rather than a constant) to return a fresh scalar every time.

```perl
sub MY_CONSTANT() { return 42 }
```

The `return` is important as it prevents the conversion of the sub to a constant.

But a better solution might be to switch to Cpanel::JSON::XS and use Cpanel::JSON::XS::Type to tell the encoder how to serialize the field.